# CSS How to erase the border from the image link?

Tags: css

here's the scenario: I have the CSS declaration

```
a { color: Red }
```

in IE, if I have:

```
<a href="...">
   <img src='...' />
</a>
```

then of course I get the red border around the image. How to get rid of it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simply:

```css
a img {
    border: none;
}
```

This sets the `border` property of any `img` element contained within an `a` element to `none`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you will get a red border as well as a blue border due to the a tag...I've noticed this in old IE browsers. Try this

```
a,
a img {
    border:none;
}
```